# Programmatically add chart to ASP.NET C# website

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have the following dataset

```
NAME | GP   | ORD_GP | EXP   | TOTAL GP | TARGET
a      206     48      -239     15         1600
b      0       27       0        27        1520
```

Im a bit stuck on how I can programatically add a chart to my webpage and bind the dataset to the chart? I have the following which is just dragged on from the toolbox.

```
   <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

any ideas on how I might bind the dataset to the chart, also I only want to show TOTAL GP and TARGET.

Answer (score 0):

The dataset should be bound to the series using f.ex.

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(xVal, yVal);
```

Besides you should change your Series declaration to:

```
<asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartArea="ChartArea1" >
```

to get your series rendered on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the chart from code behind as

```
var myChart = new Chart {
ID="myChart", Height= 100, Width =100, ...
}
```

and add the series like

```
var mySeries = new Series(){
Name ="my series", Color = Color.Red, ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line ...
}
myChart.Series.Add(mySeries);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one for binding from dataset

```
    foreach (DataRow row in urdataset.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        string seriesName = row["sno"].ToString();
        Chart1.Series.Add(seriesName);
        Chart1.Series[seriesName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        Chart1.Series[seriesName].BorderWidth = 2;

        for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex < urdataset.Tables[0].Columns.Count; colIndex++)
        {
            string columnName = urdataset.Tables[0].Columns[colIndex].ColumnName;
                YVal = Convert.ToInt32(row[columnName]);

            Chart1.Series[seriesName].Points.AddXY(columnName, YVal);
        }
    }
```